# Can a GE user download search results in KML?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz, download, search

I want to find all the grocery stores in a city on Google Earth and then download the search results as a single KML/KMZ point file. If it is possible, HOWTO isn't obvious. Other options?

Comment: ...and get something from Google for free??? Might want to try OpenStreetMap instead. The http://overpass-turbo.eu/ API is pretty good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you search a business type e.g. "grocery store," you get 10 results per page on GE. After clicking on a pin location, a new descriptive pop-up displays on the right and there is a "My Places" bookmark on the bottom left of the pop-up. Clicking the bookmark adds it to your "My Places." Repeat this as desired. After you have added your places you can export your places as a KML file.

[image]

Comment: You can use filetype: Kml "specific name" to find it in Google or Bing...